# How to call nested API on Android asynchronously?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

Let's say I want to retrieve a list of news via my Android app, like this:

> [{"title": "Hello world", "date": "0102020", "readCount: "44"}, {"title": "foo bar", "date": "03022020", "readCount: "200"}, {"title": "This is awesome", "readCount": "315"}]

and display them using RecyclerView.

For unknown reasons, the API designer made the process less straightword. First you have to call **/get-news-list**, which return the list of news IDs, like this:

> [312, 449, 518, 611, 623, 734, 755, 812]

Then with each ID as parameter, you call the **/get-new-detail**. For example **/get-news-detail/312** returns:

> {"title": "Hello world", "date": "04020202", "readCount": "132",
>   "shareCount": "150"}

I'm thinking something like this:

```
class FetchNewsDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
// process /get-news-list first
..
..

onPostExecute(){
 // now that we have the list of new IDs, call AsyncTask on each of them to retrieve the details
for (int x = 0; x < newsIDcount; x++){

}
}
```

I think my idea is cumbersome. Is there any way to simplify it?

Comment: have a look at coroutines and Rxjava2, using an AsyncTask is an old way of doing things and it will soon be deprecated, iirc

Answer (score 2):

I think you should give RxJava a try:

```
io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10
io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0
```

Then you can do the reading like this:

```
    fun getList(): Single<List<Long>> {
        TODO() //reading list of item keys
    }

    fun getItem(itemKey: Long): Single<String> {
        TODO() //reading item
    }

    fun doTheReading(compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable) {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            getList()
                .flattenAsObservable { it }
                .flatMapSingle { getItem(it) }
                .toList()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe { t1, t2 -> }
        )
    }
```

You'll also need to clear your compositeDisposable entity at some point, to make sure long running operation is not outliving your consumer.